# Android Studio screen record broken/skips record

Tags: android

I have been trying to record some test videos of my app but my system or Android Studio seems to have an issue with the encoder. I know how to use the screen capture from Android Studio because I have done it before several times. This last month, I have not been able to record any videos. The few times it was successful, the resulting mp4 could not be opened. Most of the time it skips the recording altogether and goes straight to saving the recording. Anyone have any ideas how to get the Android Studio screen record working again?

```
shell@jflteusc:/ $ screenrecord /sdcard/videoTest.mp4
screenrecord /sdcard/videoTest.mp4
WARNING: linker: libsavscmn.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
WARNING: linker: libsac3d.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
ERROR: unable to create video/avc codec instance
WARNING: failed at 1080x1920, retrying at 720x1280
ERROR: unable to create video/avc codec instance
shell@jflteusc:/ $
```

Comment: Have you tried recording through ADB command and see if that's still working?

Comment: It threw an error, i will edit my question. Looking at the error, i want to say it has something to do with the tv resolutions. I thought i commented that out though

Comment: Try rebooting the phone and/or specify a resolution and see if it helps

Comment: I attempted reboot, no success. I changed the resolution, no success. I did look into the file manager and i found the videos there from the ADB command; however, the videos will not open.